# Student course database design

Tags: ms-access, database-design

i want to create a database design for computer institute where we store student record with their previous academic and non academic course which he took in past.

student can be enrolled in more than one course in our institute and that course price can be changed in certain duration.

my question is how can i handle the changes of price in the same course when so many student are enrolled there .. here is my database design please help me how to implement this.

[link to database design]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxa01Ur3XWvNSlpySFhIbDlmLVk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean price changed in certain duration?

Does that mean that even though over time the price of the course might change, you still need it to reflect the original price that it was for each student at the moment they booked?

If so, add a "price" column to your "student_course" table, and because those entries are specific to each enrollment, you will be able to look up the price associated with that enrollment, not the current price of the course.

You obviously would keep a price column under the "course" table because that is where you get the price at the time of enrollment to be able to save under the "student_course" table when the entry is saved, but now if that changes in the future you still have price at time of enrollment.

Comment: price change in duration means that price of course can be changed after few months even duration of course  can also be changed now those students who were enrolled in previous price should reflect the original price that it was for each student at the moment they booked.> is my database design correct i've given link to it please help

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Sounds like my answer should work perfect. You don't have to change much, just add the one extra column to "student_course" (which I'm assuming is the table were each unique enrollment happens).

Then in your application when it saves the "course_id", "student_id" etc, make sure you save the "price" from the "course_detail" column as well. Now that price saved there will always reflect the original amount at time of enrollment no matter now many times the course price changes under "course_detail".. Make sense?